# VB.NET: xml childnode count is not right

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, xml-parsing

I have programmed in VB since VB-DOS, but I'm just getting started with processing XML Files. I've learned a lot, but I am having a problem with one aspect that I can't seem to overcome.

I'm running loops through child nodes at different levels, but it gets tripped up if the node has no child nodes. If the node has an `InnerText` element, I guess it is counting that as a child node, because a `ChildNodes.Count` always returns 1. And the boolean `HasChildNodes` always comes back True. And it isn't.

For example:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Name>Acme Widget</Name>
    <AssemblyDate>Mar 14, 2017</AssemblyDate>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

In this code, VB will return a `ChildNode.Count` of 2 for the node `<Item>`. That's good. But a `ChildNode.Count` for `<Name>` or `<AssemblyDate>` returns 1, even though there are zero child nodes within either node.

This is messing up my processing. Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"If the node has an `InnerText` element, I guess it is counting that as a child node, because a `ChildNodes.Count` always returns 1"*

Yes it is and rightly so, because the text is a node, specifically, text node.

You need to know the difference between *node* and *element*. There are several [types of node](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype(v=vs.110).aspx), and one of them is *text node*. `<Name>` and `<AssemblyDate>` each has one child node which is of type *text node*, and `<Item>` has 2 child nodes which are of type *element*.

You can filter child nodes by node type using LINQ [`OfType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method though, for example, to count elements only :

```
Dim element As XmlElement
....
count = element.ChildNode.OfType(Of XmlElement).Count()
```

Or, since you just started, switch to using LINQ-to-XML which is a more modern XML parser for .NET :

```
Dim element As XElement
....
count = element.Elements().Count()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. LINQ is a new area for me, I've never needed to use it before. But I have been working with it based on your response, and I have questions. (1) Your examples above include `Dim` directives without the `As` clause. Is this intentional? My IDE (VB 2010) errors with this line. (2) The `element` XmlElement/XElement is not assigned a value. Is this implied later in the '....'? My apologies for not knowing what may be intuitive for more advanced programmers. Thanks again.

Comment: @okcdev 1) it does need `As`, and 2) `element` should be set to something before used

Comment: @okcdev no.1 was my bad (should've used `As`). And yes, no.2 is as you correctly assumed. `...` supposed to be replaced with codes where you populate the `element`, since we have no idea of where the XML come from in your case (string variable, a file?). As for general example, there are a ton of article/tutorial/MSDN documentation on that topic already..

Comment: @Slai, jdweng and har07 - Using the advice from all of you I looked further into LINQ functionality and was able use it to do what I needed to do. I appreciate the help, and the incentive to learn a new functionality. I went ahead and marked this one as the answer, though all of the responses were of great help. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, my low reputation score would not allow me to upvote any of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

User xml linq.  The tag names are case sensitive so I changed name to Name.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("Item").Select(Function(x) New With { _
                                                         .name = x.Element("Name"),
                                                         .date = CType(x.Element("AssemblyDate"), DateTime)
                                                     }).ToList()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Please read my response to har07. The site would not let me include more than one extra user reference, nor would my low reputation score allow me to make an upvote. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @har07's answer, I would also highly recommend looking into the more modern way of [XML to LINQ in VB.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384833) that is integrated directly into the VB.Net language with [XML Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384629):

```
    Dim x = <Items>
                <Item>
                    <Name>Acme Widget</Name>
                    <AssemblyDate>Mar 14, 2017</AssemblyDate>
                </Item>
            </Items>

    Dim c0 = x.<Item>.Descendants.Count '' 2
    Dim c1 = x.<Item>.Elements.Count    '' 2
    Dim c2 = x.<Item>.Nodes.Count       '' 2

    Dim c3 = x...<Name>.Elements.Count  '' 0
    Dim c4 = x...<Name>.Nodes.Count     '' 1
```